# What is the proper way to handle multiple conditionals in a wxpython file dialog?

Tags: wxpython, filedialog

My wxpython GUI has a method for opening a FileDialog:

```
def open_filedlg(self,event):
    dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, "Choose XYZ file", getcwd(), "",
             "XYZ files (*.dat)|*.dat|(*.xyz)|*.xyz", wx.OPEN)
    if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
         self.xyz_source=str(dlg.GetPath())
         self.fname_txt_ctl.SetValue(self.xyz_source)
         dlg.Destroy()
         return
    if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_CANCEL:
         dlg.Destroy()
         return
```

If I want to cancel, I have to hit the "Cancel" button twice.  If I reverse the order of the conditionals, Cancel works OK, but then I have to hit the "Open" button twice to get a file name.  Using "elif" instead of the second "if" doesn't change the behavior.  What is the correct way to do this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that you are opening the dialog twice (once with each 'dlg.ShowModal').

Try something like

```
dialogStatus = dlg.ShowModal()
if dialogStatus == wx.ID_OK:
    ...
```

Comment: and then use if/elif/else for multiple conditionals.

Answer (score 3):

With newer versions of wxPython (2.8.11+) I would use the context manager, like this:

```
def open_filedlg(self,event):
    with wx.FileDialog(self, "Choose XYZ file", getcwd(), "",
             "XYZ files (*.dat)|*.dat|(*.xyz)|*.xyz", wx.OPEN) as dlg:
        dlgResult = dlg.ShowModal()
        if dlgResult == wx.ID_OK:
            self.xyz_source=str(dlg.GetPath())
            self.fname_txt_ctl.SetValue(self.xyz_source)
            return
        else:
            return
        #elif dlgResult == wx.ID_CANCEL:
            #return
```

The 'with' context manager will automagically call dlg.destroy().

Comment: Thanks.  Apparently my version is not new enough.  The context manager gives and AttributeError.  It doesn't like something about "__exit__".

Comment: @bob.sacamento what version of wxPython are you using?  Can you show the full traceback?